# Set Cookies from servlet java HttpURLConnection per individual user

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, http-headers

I have an API servlet java application that let users view an external page by his user and password, the view URL need the cookies to be set before calling it

I use this code to view the page

```
            CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
            CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
            String request_url = "http://url/view.jsp?id"+ id;
            URL url = new URL(request_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(20000);
            httpURLConnection.connect();

            try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()))) {
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    data = data + inputLine;
                    helper.status = 0;
                    helper.errorDesc = "0";
                }

                in.close();
            }

            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
```

if it returns no access data I use this code to login with user credential

```
            CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
            CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
            String urlParameters = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&displayLangCode=" + lang  + "&langCode=" + lang;
            System.out.println("urlParameters" + urlParameters);
            byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            int postDataLength = postData.length;
            String activeUrl = "http://url/login.jsp";
            URL url = new URL(activeUrl);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Service", "AuthenticateUser");
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));
            httpURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            httpURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(20000);
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream())) {
                wr.write(postData);
                wr.close();
            }
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
```

it's working fine and I can get the content,

**the issue is that if another user makes the call to view the content he can see the content as the first user that logged in**

that mean the cookies has been set by API level, not by user level,

I need a help because I have no idea how I can resolve this cookies issue to set cookies per user call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to fix this issue by disabling the automatic cookies

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_NONE);
```

then in the login method, I am extracting the cookies and return it from the function

```
List<String> cookies = httpURLConnection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
String token = null;
if (cookies != null) {
 for (String cookie : cookies) {
  token = cookie.split(";", 1)[0];
 }
}
return token
```

then every time when calling the view function we passing the cookies

```
httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("Cookie", token);
```